# Как изменить строку кода адаптера для соответствия фрагменту?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, adapter

У меня есть `CursorAdapter` для `RecyclerView`, написанный для активности, я решил перенести список в фрагмент, но не могу понять, как нужно изменить строку кода что бы она соответствовала фрагменту?

```
    public MyListCursorAdapter(Context context,Cursor cursor)
{
    super(context,cursor);
    this.context = context;
    this.activity = (HistoryActivity) context;
}
```

это часть кода из адаптера для обычной активности, когда я пытаюсь переделать его под фрагмент студия ругается на  `this.activity = (HistoryActivity) context;`. К сожалению я очень плохо понимаю суть контекста, я пробовал менять `HistoryActivity` на 
`History_fragment`, это слишком наивно и не работает)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Из любого места фрагмента Вы можете получить активность методом `getActivity()`, а вот держать ссылку на активность внутри фрагмента - плохая идея, по-моему. Потому как в какой-то момент Вы можете получить ссылку на старую, уже разрушенную активность, что может стать причиной вызова исключения.

Так что просто уберите строку:

```
this.activity = (HistoryActivity) context;
```

и в местах, где используется `this.activity`, вызывайте `getActivity()`.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте передать в адаптер ссылку на фрагмент.

```
public MyListCursorAdapter(Fragment fragment, Cursor cursor){
    super(fragment.getContext(), cursor);
    this.context = context;
    this.activity = (HistoryActivity) fragment.getActivity();
    this.fragment = fragment;
}
```